# I Can't Connect a Laptop Wirelessly to my FTP Server [Weird Issue?]

Tags: wireless-networking, router, laptop, ftp, connection

I have an FTP server running on my PC. I am able to connect to it perfectly fine on PC. I can connect to it from my bosses laptop fine. But I can't connect from my co-workers laptop at all.

We are all on the same network. However both me and my boss are hardwired. When I plug in an ethernet cable from the PC to the Laptop it connects fine, but it doesn't connect wirelessly. Also, when I connect it to a different ethernet port on the same network it doesn't work either. Just a direct connect to the server PC works.

I have checked that Port 21 is open. I have checked the firewall and made sure there are rules for Port 21.

I am using WinSCP. I should be able to just select "FTP", put in the IP address of the server, and then hit "anonymous connect" and login like I do from my bosses laptop, or like I can do from the PC.

How do I get it to connect wirelessly? Or do I need to have my co-workers laptop hardwired for it to work?

Thanks for the help, this is my first time doing an FTP server.

Comment: Sounds like the wireless access point DNS server is different then the network device connected to the Ethernet connection.  It would very unusual for a corporate environment to use the same physical device for both.  You can be connected to the same network but be using a different dns server.

Comment: They're the same in this office. It's kind of a ghetto set up since it's in a remote community.